# Determining the probability of measuring spin state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am having some problems figuring out the following question regarding probabilities of spin states.

**The Question**

Consider the spinor
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
What is the probability that a measurement of the operator $\frac{3{S_x}+4S_y}{5}$ yields $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$?

**My approach**

First, rewriting the operator into a single matrix, using the Pauli spin matrices
$$\frac{3{S_x}+4S_y}{5}=\frac{3}{5}*\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0   \end{pmatrix}+\frac{4}{5}*\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0   \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac{\hbar}{10}(3-4i)\\ \frac{\hbar}{10}(3+4i)&0   \end{pmatrix}$$

Next, finding the eigenvalues of this matrix,
$$\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&\frac{\hbar}{10}(3-4i)\\ \frac{\hbar}{10}(3+4i)&-\lambda   \end{vmatrix}=\lambda^2-\frac{\hbar^2}{4}=0 \rightarrow \lambda =\pm\frac{\hbar}{2}$$
Then find the eigenstates,
$$\frac{\hbar}{10}\begin{pmatrix}0&3-4i\\ 3+4i&0   \end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix}$$
gives us,
$$\pm5a=(3-4i)b$$
Now taking $a=1$, gives $b=\frac{5}{3-4i}$

normalizing the state vector, gives us
$$\chi_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\\frac{5}{3-4i}\end{bmatrix}$$ 
and 
$$\chi_-=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\\frac{-5}{3-4i}\end{bmatrix}$$ 
We can now write the generic spinor $\chi$ as a linear combination of both $\chi_+$ and $\chi_-$
$$\chi=\big(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{5b}{\sqrt{2}(3-4i)}\big)\chi_++\big(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{5b}{\sqrt{2}(3-4i)}\big)\chi_-$$

Therefore, the probability of measuring $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ is equal to the following,
$$P(-\frac{\hbar}{2})=\big|\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{5b}{\sqrt{2}(3-4i)}\big|^2=\frac{1}{2}\big|a-\frac{5b}{3-4i}\big|^2$$
In this case $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so $a=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$
Filling in these values into the probability equation, we find
$$P(-\frac{\hbar}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\big|\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{\frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}}{3-4i}\big|^2=0.26$$

I am not sure if I am approaching the problem correctly and I was wondering whether anyone could verify this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Why do you doubt this method? This might not be the best place to look for a yes or no answer, but maybe you could make it clear why you are not sure if it is right?

PS: You can further convince yourself by checking that the probability of finding the other state is $P(\hbar/2) = 1 - P(-\hbar/2)$.